# Auto-Save input made by users - the most smartest way to implement this?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm developing a social network website and I'm working with php/mysql/jquery and I want users to have the most user-friendly website experience. That's why I try to avoid a save (submit) button at all. So, when they're on their own profile and enter information like what languages they speak or where do they live, I want to auto-create a page entry, if it doesn't exists already.

For example if somebody speaks german and that entry isn't available in the database yet (it's called `pages` with rows `title`,`text`,`date_added`). This is most likely comperable with a Facebook page you can create on Facebook, but this should be about everything (languages, companies, locations, activities).

So my specific problem is now, how to implement this feature the most smartest way. I mean on what event should this save be triggered, because I obviously can't save a new entry on every letter that has been typed. I've already implemented an autocomplete function, so they can choose from entries that already exist, but as mentioned I want them to create new entries (pages), too. Most preferably without "flooding" the database with new entries.

The things I thought of:

1. When a user switches from one input to another and input has been
   made. Can this even be registered by JQuery? But here's the
   question, what if he leaves the page without switching to another
   input.
2. Save all data only then if he leaves the current page. I think
       there is this `onunload` function in JQuery.
3. Get confirmation from the user: "This entry hasn't been made yet.
       Do you want to save this entry?". But when should I ask this? I
       can't predict when the user is finished with typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

1) Every time the user presses a button or clicks inside an input field - register a timeout using `setTimeout` (if the timeout was already set - clear it). The actual timeout in ms is up to you, it depends on the users and the data they are entering - maybe half a second or a whole second will be fine.

2) Inside the timeout - submit the data to the backend

3) And as you mentioned - if the user attempts to leave the page with a timeout waiting to happen - ask him if he really wants to leave. Keep in mind you are limited in what you can do from the unload handler itself, so it is best just to return him to the page and invoke the save then (as AJAX will probably not work from that handler, or at least it will not be consistent in all browsers).

```
var to = null;
$(':input').on('click contextmenu keyup blur', function () {
  if(to) { clearTimeout(to); }
  to = setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax(...send data to server...).done(function () {
      // possibly show a message indicating the data was saved
    })
  }, 1000);
});
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if(to) {
    return "Are you sure you want to navigate away, you have unsaved data?";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but wouldn't this be too much data-send-overload if there are hundreds of users?

Comment: That depends on way too many factors (like server performance, backend code quality, network connectivity, data amount, etc). However I doubt hundreds of users will be a problem.

Comment: I tried this code and I wanted to understand it better, but the part with the timeout confuses me a bit. My solution is that in the autocomplete field there is the option "Add (input)". So every input can be saved if you select that. Now I have the issue that I can't unset `to`, even if I've added data. I tried: `to = null;` and `clearTimeout(to)` in the relevant code after data has been saved. In my new question you can see my actual code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30526992/jquery-ui-autocomplete-add-custom-values-prevent-duplicates-and-allow-spaces